# Trying to write paragraphs with Google Script in Automated email response

Tags: google-apps-script

I am trying to make a simple paragraph where I can enter a few lines of text, but am not picking it up very easily. Can I switch it to html in the script or is there an easier way to write a template paragraph?

My current script looks like this where I am making an automated email response whenever someone fills out a form (conference registration). Currently, everything in my message section comes out as one block.

I would like to be able to have a few paragraphs in the email such as "Don't forget to mail payment to (Address)" and then the "registration" answer to list as its own line as well with text before it.

Also, I want to be able to display the Tuesday- Thursday answers in a bulleted list.

```
function myFunction(e){ 
  var userName = e.values[2]; 
  var userEmail = e.values[11];
  var Registration = e.values[1]; 
  var Tuesday = e.values[16]; 
  var Wednesday = e.values[17]; 
  var Thursday = e.values[18]; 
  var Friday = e.values[19]; 
  var subject = "Conference Registration"; 
  var Message = "Thank you for Registering for the Conference," + userName + "You have following registration type: " + Registration; 
  var message = "You have registered for the following sessions: " + Tuesday + Wednesday + Thursday + Friday;

  MailApp.sendEmail(userEmail, subject, message); 
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned in the other answer, you can create html content in an email message, below is a simple example of how to do that based on your question.

*btw I added a script to simulate a form sending so it will be much easier to test (without needing to send hundreds of forms while you play with html tags)*

About **HTML tags**, a [Google search](https://www.google.be/search?q=html%20tags&oq=html%20tags&aqs=chrome..69i57j0l5.3070j0j1&sourceid=chrome&es_sm=119&ie=UTF-8) on these words will show you far more tips and tricks that I could ever do in this answer... *enjoy !*

**note** : in the example below I changed the e.values indexes to simplify my test code... don't forget to re-adapt !

### Code :

```
function testMyFunction(){ 
  var e = {};
  e.values = ['test user Name','test user Email','test Registration',' event on Tuesday','event on Wednesday','party on Thursday','nothing on Friday'];
  myFunction(e);
}

function myFunction(e){ 
  var userName = e.values[0]; 
  var userEmail = e.values[1];
  var Registration = e.values[2]; 
  var Tuesday = e.values[3]; 
  var Wednesday = e.values[4]; 
  var Thursday = e.values[5]; 
  var Friday = e.values[6]; 
  var subject = "Conference Registration"; 
  var htmlMessage = "Thank you for Registering for the Conference," + userName + "<br>You have following registration type: <li>" + Registration; 
  htmlMessage+=Tuesday+'</li><li>'+Wednesday+'</li><li>'+ Thursday+'</li><li>'+Friday+'</li>';

  Logger.log(htmlMessage);
  MailApp.sendEmail(Session.getActiveUser().getEmail(), subject,'html content',{htmlBody : htmlMessage}); 
}
```

Result screen capture :

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use html formatting in your body, when you are calling sendEmail do it like this:

`MailApp.sendEmail({
  to: userEmail,
  subject: subject,
  htmlBody: message
});`

This will tell Gmail to interpret the message variable as HTML and not just raw text.